# What is the lifespan of demons?

Tags: sheidim-demons

I tried to Google the answer myself but I can't find one. I tried to find the answer using chatgpt 4 but to no avail.

Comment: Why do you assume they are mortal?

Comment: @Eliyahu I believe it's entirely possible that demons are mortal beings just like humans. I assume they can even be slayed. But only those who are worthy can possess these powers.

Comment: @Eliyahu https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.16a.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he&with=all "ששה דברים נאמרו בשדים...ומתים כבני אדם".

Comment: Six words were spoken by demons, three as ministering angels, and three as human beings.

Comment: ושלשה כבני אדם אוכלין ושותין כבני אדם פרין ורבין כבני אדם ומתים כבני אדם 
And in three ways they are similar to humans: They eat and drink like humans; they multiply like humans; and they die like humans.
Chagigah 16a7
The William Davidson Talmud(Koren - Steinsaltz) @Eliyahu

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%98